# How to: Allow a ViewPager to function normally whilst passing touch events to a view the ViewPager is overlapping

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener, android-tablayout, android-touch-event

I have a TabLayout and a ViewPager which contains the tabs.

The ViewPager is positioned above the TabLayout so that the ViewPager overlaps the TabLayout, and as a result, the TabLayout buttons which navigate between the different tabs do not work because the ViewPager is intercepting the touch events.

I've tried to fix the issue by calling `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` on the ViewPager and it didn't fix the issue.

I also created a custom ViewPager and overrode the onTouchEvent() method like this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getActionMasked() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }
```

This allows the TabLayout tab buttons to receive the touch events but the ViewPager doesn't scroll automatically to the different fragments when the ViewPager is scrolled a sufficient amount.

**The problem in a nutshell:** How do I allow the TabLayout which the ViewPager is overlapping to receive the touch events that the ViewPager is intercepting before the TabLayout, whilst allowing the ViewPager to function properly?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Here is a basic XML representation of the Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity"

    >


    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@color/purple_light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:clickable="true"
        />


    <CustomViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:clickable="false"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:** I made it seem like the ViewPager pages are below the TabLayout by setting the top margin of the TabLayout fragments enough for them to display below the TabLayout

Here is a basic diagram of the Activity before the views (which function to reveal other fullscreen views `onClick`) inside the ViewPager are expanded

[image: unexpanded layout]

And here is a basic diagram of my Activity after a clicked view in the pager has revealed the other content:

[image]

You can see in the second diagram **the TabLayout is covered by the ViewPager content**

Comment: Why is the view pager overlapping the Tabs? It seems like fixing that would solve the issue.

Comment: If the ViewPager wasn't overlapping the TabLayout then this would indeed allow the TabLayout to receive the touch events. But the tabs contain views which I need to expand to the extend that they are overlapping the TabLayout, so that the expanded view is underneath the Toolbar and not beneath the TabLayout and the Toolbar

Comment: Could you post your XML and also diagram what you are trying to achieve. There may be ways of achieving your goals without the overlapping issues.

Comment: I edited my question and posted a basic representation of my XML layout and provided two basic diagrams of the layout I am trying to create. Let me know if the diagrams aren't clear enough

Comment: So can the user even see the tabbar when the view is expanded? How will they know where to click? It seems like having a reveal effect such as swipe down to reveal tabbar would be a better solution.

Comment: When the view is expanded the user can't see the TabLayout. When the view is expanded, the activity looks like like they've entered into  a non-tabbed activity. If the user wants to return to the tabbed activity they just press the back button. Having a swipe down to reveal the TabLayout could work, but, if the user is switching frequently between the tabs, and they want to switch between the tabs by clicking between them, it might become frustrating for users to have to reveal the TabLayout so that they can click on it

Comment: The view pager should allow switching without showing the tabs by simply swiping left/right.

Comment: The ViewPager does allow people to switch tabs by swiping, but I've been told that having the buttons working functionally would be good, and I'd rather have the buttons functional if it's possible to do so

Comment: IMO, either A. Don't hide the tabs or B. show the tabs to click them.  No user is going to expect clicking where the tabs used to be and expect it to work. If I encountered that in an app I would think it is a bug.

Comment: But I think that your comment 'No user is going to expect clicking where the tabs used to be and expect it to work' is a result of you misunderstanding my layout. When the view is expanded, it looks like you've entered a new activity, the tabs are not visible. Perhaps I can  fix the issue by customizing the ViewPager in a better way, or put two  transparent views over the TabLayout which will pass the onTouch events to the TabLayouts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111244/discussion-between-cyroxis-and-micah-simmons).

Comment: Don't worry about it, I solved the issue by putting a view over the ViewPager and TabLayout. The view is positioned exactly where the TabLayout is, and it  intercepts the touch events before the ViewPager, and it switches between the tabs by calling viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabIndex)